# how intermediaries in freelancing work?

Tags: freelance-websites

i am a freelance web developer and i have worked with a couple of clients who are not running a business themselves but they are individuals who get projects from the "**real**" clients and outsource it to me. So essentialy they are standing in between me and the real clients. So my question is:

1. What do you call such a person? or what is their designation? Is it correct to refer to them as contractors?
2. How do they get their projects?

Thanks

Comment: They are probably someone from the same field as you but with more experience. They gathered their own pool of client who are able to bring new projects constantly. This is a usually thing. I used to work on projects work 5M+ where I was paid my hourly rate :). It's just the way things flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called recruitment agencies.

A recruitment agency is a company that acts as a middle man between the client and the contractor.  Their services are mostly recruitment but some may offer project management too. They get their projects in the same way contractors do, by applying for projects online or by advertising their services as an agency.

Usually an agency will have a pool of skilled contractors at their disposal and will take a percentage cut of the payment. The quality of the agency is very important,  some specialise in very skilled contractors and are very efficient and good managers, others can offer low quality service and generally aren't worth the effort.

Usually a client will hire an agency when they don't have the time or knowledge to manage the recruitment process but just want the job done.

Comment: I call them clients as they are my clients :).

Comment: @Stacey : Vote up requires 15 reputation. So +1 and thanks :)